# dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier takes 4 seconds to run when storyboard label has custom fonts

Tags: ios, fonts, storyboard

I've got an app that has a series of views transitioned via navigationController's pushViewController.  The final step is a push of a view containing a tableView, and tableViewCell prototype.  This transition was taking 4 seconds to complete at which time the UI hangs before the push visually occurs.

I narrowed it down to the call to *dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier* for the first time.  I then narrowed it down to one or more labels that contained custom fonts loaded in the project.

I was able to fix it by leaving the storyboard font as System, but dynamically assigning the custom font in the code.

My question is why does setting the font in storyboard make this so much slower, and can anything be done to fix that? I'd prefer to have it set in storyboard like the rest of the attributes.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"tableViewCell";

    // The next line takes 4 seconds to run 
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    NSDictionary *data = _data[indexPath.section][indexPath.row];

    UILabel *label1 = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    UILabel *label2 = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    UILabel *label3 = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:3];

    // Using this instead of storyboard defined fonts loads quickly
    // label1.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Oxygen-Bold" size:18];
    // label2.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Semibold" size:13];
    // label3.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Semibold" size:13];

    label1.text = data[@"name"];
    label2.text = data[@"subtitle"];
    label3.text = data[@"slogan"];

    return cell;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have spent a day trying to figure out why my *dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier* taking 1 second for adding new Custom Cell on iOS 8 (on iOS 7 – works great).

Fixed by removing Custom Font from storyboard. Thank you so much for the hint.

That's decently a bug by Apple.

Comment: To my surprise, doing the opposite fixed the delay issue in my case. I was setting the font programmatically and getting 4 seconds delay as described in the question. I commented out the font setting code and used storyboards instead and the delay is gone!